# Installation of Geopandas for Windows 10

Tags: python, geopandas

There are some problems about geopandas installation for Windows 10 system. You know that this module is including some dependencies into widerange. In this mean, I presented as snapshots my system responses with this dependencies as a summary.

What is the problem?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The error just says it cannot find the file it needs in your Environment Path. Navigate to your cmd terminal and try:

```
conda install geopandas
```

Alternatively you can grab the install and all dependencies from the forge:

```
conda install --channel conda-forge geopandas
```

Comment: conda-forge is the officially recommended way of installing geopandas rather than an alternative ;).

Answer (score 1):

It gets  easy when you create new environment for it, then start installing. I had followed a lot procedure, downloading wheel files and installing manually but creating the environment and then installing (using Anaconda) make it lot easier.

I have followed this from https://geopandas.org/getting_started/install.html

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4df9z.png)

```
conda create -n geo_env
conda activate geo_env
conda config --env --add channels conda-forge
conda config --env --set channel_priority strict
conda install python=3 geopandas
```